# I wanted to flash a message on my screen every hour

Tags: automation

So I just put it on the Task Scheduler to open this .txt every hour but it always ends up opening up the "Open with" menu and giving me "Acess denied" when I choose the program. Does anybody know of a better way of doing this? I'm on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download "messagebox" or a similar program, designed to put messages on the screen, rather than trying to display a textfile.  I use the program from http://www.optimumx.com/downloads.html -- I'm including the page link on the latter as it has several other useful utilities.  This creates a windows-style message box, with lots of options -- i.e. you could set it to display a box with no controls (buttons) that will go away after x number of seconds.

The command is very simple, just put in the "action" section of your Windows Task Scheduler something like:

```
c:\<full path to MessageBox>\MessageBox.exe
```

and on the parameters field, you should put:

```
/C:Whatever caption (title) /M:this is the content /W:display for x seconds
```

If you use 
`messagebox /T:?` it will show the different button options for /T: (OK, Cancel, no buttons, etc.)

- /C:  specifies the caption to display in the title bar.
- /M:   specifies the message to display to the user.
- /W:   number of seconds to wait before timing out (optional).
- /T:   specifies the type of icon and buttons (optional).
- /T:?  Displays extended help for /T: options and return codes.

To display multiple lines, separate them with \n;  to tab, use \t.

One warning, it doesn't work if the total command is more than 256 chars, but that usually will get you 4-5 lines of text displayed.

Here's an example with the results (which will stay on screen for 10 seconds):

```
    E:\sources\MessageBox\MessageBox.exe /C:sample caption
 /M:this would be the \t\nmulti-line message\t /W:10 /T:35
```

[image: Sample image from command]

Comment: The readme file doesn't help a lot. How do you use this program? It seems promising

Comment: It's very simple -- like this:

Comment: It's very simple -- like this, for example:  "messagebox.exe /C:Whatever caption (title) /M:this is the content /W:display for so many seconds".  If you use "messagebox /T:?" it will show the different button options for /T: (OK, Cancel, no buttons, etc.)
 /C: specifies the caption to display in the title bar.
 /M: specifies the message to display to the user.
 /W: number of seconds to wait before timing out (optional).
 /T: specifies the type of icon and buttons (optional).
 /T:? Displays extended help for /T: options and return codes.
\\n in a string inserts a new line; \\t inserts a tab.

Comment: Sorry, missed the window to edit the first comment!

Comment: The task scheduler has a built in option to show a message box...

Comment: There are features in messagebox that I particularly like, including being able to specify the buttons & how long it stays on the screen. But it all depends on the actual requirements, as sahmeepee notes.

Comment: That would actually be more according to the behavior that I actually want although I'm using sahmeepee's solution right now. Where do these commands you talk about go? The customization options seem really great

Comment: You can run the command directly as a scheduled task, or put it in a batch file (esp. if you want additional actions) or even set a batch file that runs in the background & just waits for each period of time, then re-runs the command.  Just be sure to use the full path for the "messagebox.exe" program. For example, you could have a batch file that tests for a running program, and only displays the message if the program is open.  The "timeout" command is useful for looping in a batch file & then waiting before reiterating.

Answer (score 3):

You could try specifying the full command you are trying to run, e.g.:

"C:\Windows\notepad.exe"

with the full path to the file you want to open as the arguments.

Comment: The reservation that I have with this method is that the user must keep closing the file that's opened.

Comment: I would imagine that's useful so you are sure it has been seen. Depends on the requirements!